# Como recuperar todos os eventos que estão no FullCalendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fullcalendar

Eu tenho uma página que possui uma lista de eventos que podem ser arrastados para um FullCalendar.

Após arrastar todos os meus eventos para o FullCalendar e clicar no botão concluir eu quero pegar uma lista, ou algo do tipo, com todos os eventos e em que data este evento foi colocado.

Como posso fazer isso usando o FullCalendar em ASP.NET?

Minha Página (HTML)

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FullCalendar._Default" %>


<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div id='wrap'>
        <div id='external-events'>
            <h4>
                Servicos Complementares</h4>
            <div class='fc-event'>
                Servico 1
            </div>
            <div class='fc-event'>
                Servico 2
            </div>
            <div class='fc-event'>
                Servico 3
            </div>
            <div class='fc-event'>
                Servico 4
            </div>
            <div class='fc-event'>
                Servico 5
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
                <label for='drop-remove'>
                    Remover após a escolha da data</label>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id='calendar'>
        </div>
        <div style='clear: both'>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Vejam que nesta página eu tenho (Servico 1, Servico 2, Servico 3, etc).

Eu também um FullCalendar na `<div id='calendar'>`.

Eu arrasto estes serviços (Servico 1, Servico 2, Servico 3, etc) para dentro do meu FullCalendar, cada um em uma data especifica.

Veja como fica:

[image: FullCalendar preenchido com os serviços da lista]

Agora que os serviços estão no no calendário eu quero, ao clicar em um botão, obter uma lista com os serviços que estão no calendário e com a respectiva data em que cada serviço esta posicionado no calendário.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, pode postar o código ?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa adicionei mais informações e trechos de código para deixar a minha pergunta mais clara.

Comment: Por que não utiliza o Calendar do ASP.NET?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Ele não atende as minhas necessidades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que sua melhor opção não é pegar os eventos no concluir, e sim já ir tratando os eventos conforme sejam inseridos no calendário. O FullCalendar possui uma gama de events que podem ser disparados conforme sua necessidade. Especificamente o evento 'drop' que dispara uma função enviando como parâmetros 'date', 'jsEvent', 'ui'. Armaena esses Eventos em um Object e simplesmente o envie quando concluir.

Obs: Lembrar de tratar também os demais métodos para eventos que forem alterados ou removidos depois de "dropados". A documentação completa dos eventos pode ser encontrada em http://fullcalendar.io/docs/

EDIT:

Fiz um jsfiddle do exemplo que citei... Não está profissional porque estava com pressa, mas está didático:
Fiz um fiddle meio nas carreiras, mas tem aqui um exemplo do que eu falei:

http://jsfiddle.net/romulotorres/tz30ujx8/

Com esse objeto criado, você transforma no que quiser

Comment: Obrigado @RomuloTorres Já estou lendo a documentação e fazendo algumas experiências, mas até agora ainda não achei uma solução para o problema. Se você puder postar um código de exemplo de como seria a solução que você propôs eu ficaria muito agradecido.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo na própria resposta lá em cima. Se for útil, não esqueça de votar na pergunta. E se resolve seu problema, marcar como resposta certa para finalizar o tópico. Abraço

Comment: Não funcionou @LeonardoRibeirodeAguiar?

Comment: @RomuloOTorres funcionou perfeitamente. Até melhor do que eu queria, muito obrigado.